# Images stored in vector are all identical

Tags: c++, qt, camera

I am creating a C++ application to record images with a camera using the Spinnaker library. To improve performance, I decided to temporarily store the images in a vector and save them afterward. But since I decided to save them after, all images are identical (despite the fact that the camera is still moving) and I don't understand why...

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
CameraPtr pCam = camList.GetByIndex(0);
unsigned int imageCnt = 0;
pCam->BeginAcquisition();
vector<ImagePtr> images;

QTime t_end = QTime::currentTime();
t_end = t_end.addSecs(sb_duration->value());

while (QTime::currentTime() < t_end) {          
    ImagePtr pResultImage = pCam->GetNextImage();
    images.push_back(pResultImage);
    pResultImage->Release();
}

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++)
{
    ostringstream filename;
    filename << s_folder << "/Image #" << i << ".jpg";

    ImagePtr pResultImage = images[i];
    pResultImage->Save(filename.str().c_str());

    i_progress = ((double) i / imageCnt) * 50 + 50;
    p_progress->setValue(i_progress);

    qInfo() << "Image #" << i << "saved.";
}

pCam->DeInit();
```

Comment: Why are you releasing the image after storing it? The ImagePtr is a pointer to image, I assume if you release the pointer (ImagePtr), you are erasing the image.

Comment: At a glance, you release the image, while keeping pointer to it.  That is very  suspicious. Is that valid? (Unfamiliar with spinnaker library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use the DeepCopy function:

```
while (QTime::currentTime() < t_end) {          
    ImagePtr pResultImage = pCam->GetNextImage();
    ImagePtr pCopyImage = Image::Create();
    pCopyImage->DeepCopy(ip_ResultImage);
    images.push_back(pCopyImage);
    pResultImage->Release();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I commented before in the comment, and after checking a bit the [documentation](https://www.ptgrey.com/Content/Images/uploaded/downloads/Software/2016/Spinnaker/html/index.html), ImagPtr is an 'smart pointer' to manage the resource [Image](https://www.ptgrey.com/Content/Images/uploaded/downloads/Software/2016/Spinnaker/html/class_spinnaker_1_1_image.html#a94c93747c8daa99d65c2a04c6be0748c) in your code. But when you write this line `pResultImage->Release();` you are erasing directly the image, so you lost  it.

I recommend you should delete this line and avoid releasing the image, and then you can see the image you store in the vector.

Comment: I did as you suggested but it just causes the program to record a few images before freezing. Furthemore I looked into an example from the documentation where it stores images into a vector and there is the pResultImage->Release() line.However they convert the image before saving it:
images.push_back(pResultImage->Convert(PixelFormat_Mono8, HQ_LINEAR));
This solutions works but reduce significantly the performances (from 150 FPS to 60)...

Comment: Well, pResultImage is a resource that you should release when you finish using it, so when you only store the images in a vector, the program crashes when you overflow the heap. I am not sure what you are trying to do, but you need release the image after you use it. In the example you mention it, the performance is greatly reduces because convert is an operation that it costs, event when the operation only transforms the image in monochrome color space.